# Combining many camel components into one custom component

Tags: apache-camel

I want to create a new camel component `MyComponent` that's a combination of different components:

For example, instead of specifying multiple endpoints:

```
from("file:c:/in")...to...

from("ftp:...")...to...
```

I want a `MyComponent` that can detect the right endpoint:

```
from("myComponent:..")...to...
```

so that it works as an adapter whether the file came `from("file")`, `from("sftp")`, `from("stream")`, etc...

And works as an adapter eater we have a file as entry or ftp ..

How could this be achieved?

Comment: I edited your post (it's in the queue) to clarify it a little bit, but I couldn't tell what you meant in this line: "And works as an adapter eater we have a file as entry or ftp .." Could you try to make sense of that?

Comment: @gkubed I mean i don't want to use different entry points as the first example : from("file") from("sftp") from("stream") I want that mu component do all the job and detect the right entrypoint when I do from("mycomponent") it can be a file or a stream or anything

Comment: To me, this looks like YAGNI.

Answer (score 5):

Do you really need camel component or you can achieve that with custom route builder? Here is just raw example to show general idea:

Custom route builder class instead of component:

```java
import org.apache.camel.Endpoint;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.component.file.FileEndpoint;
import org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.FtpConfiguration;
import org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.FtpEndpoint;

class MyFileReader extends RouteBuilder {
    private String name;
    private String dir;
    private String mask;
    private String ftpHost;
    private int ftpPort;
    private String ftpUser;
    private String ftpPass;
    private boolean ftpMode;

    public MyFileReader(String name, String dir, String mask) {
        this.name = name;
        this.dir = dir;
        this.mask = mask;
        this.ftpMode = false;
    }

    public MyFileReader(String name, String dir, String mask, String ftpHost, int ftpPort, String ftpUser, String ftpPass) {
        this.name = name;
        this.dir = dir;
        this.mask = mask;
        this.ftpHost = ftpHost;
        this.ftpPort = ftpPort;
        this.ftpUser = ftpUser;
        this.ftpPass = ftpPass;
        this.ftpMode = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from(initFromEndpoint()).to("direct:" +name + "_out");
    }

    private Endpoint initFromEndpoint() {
        if (ftpMode) {
            FtpEndpoint endpoint = new FtpEndpoint();
            FtpConfiguration configuration = endpoint.getConfiguration();
            configuration.setHost(ftpHost);
            configuration.setPort(ftpPort);
            configuration.setUsername(ftpUser);
            configuration.setPassword(ftpPass);
            configuration.setDirectory(dir);
            endpoint.setInclude(mask);
            return endpoint;
        } else {
            FileEndpoint endpoint = new FileEndpoint();
            endpoint.getConfiguration().setDirectory(dir);
            endpoint.setInclude(mask);
            return endpoint;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage example from Spring xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd

       http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">

    <bean id="fileReader" class="MyFileReader">
        <constructor-arg name="name" value="myFileReader" />
        <constructor-arg name="dir" value="/myfiles" />
        <constructor-arg name="mask" value="*.txt" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="ftpReader" class="MyFileReader">
        <constructor-arg name="name" value="myFtpReader" />
        <constructor-arg name="dir" value="/myftpfiles" />
        <constructor-arg name="mask" value="*.txt" />
        <constructor-arg name="ftpHost" value="127.0.0.1" />
        <constructor-arg name="ftpPort" value="1234" />
        <constructor-arg name="ftpUser" value="myuser" />
        <constructor-arg name="ftpPass" value="mypass" />
    </bean>

    <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" id="integration-schedule" useMDCLogging="true">
        <routeBuilder ref="fileReader" />
        <routeBuilder ref="ftpReader" />

        <route id="fileRoute">
            <from uri="direct:fileReader_out" />
            <log message="Do something with files" />
        </route>

        <route id="ftpRoute">
            <from uri="direct:ftpReader_out" />
            <log message="Do something with ftp files" />
        </route>
    </camelContext>
</beans>
```

Comment: I believe component is overhead there. Component required when you need to communicate with something that is not implemented in camel or camel implementation is not working. For the rest cases like to specify java class with some parameters which depending on them will build different routes it's much easier to use custom route builder class

Comment: Let me upvote this answer, as I also believe that you are working against fundamental Camel concepts. You really should stick to separate components as they are, even for the sake of already established standards.